# How can Enable Product (a [website] scope property) can have different values in one specific store view vs All Store?

Tags: magento2, products, scope, default-values, enable-disable

I have 1 website, 1 store and 2 store views (for English and Finnish languages.),
If "Enable product" scope is *website*. Then how come it can have different values between these Scope: Default vs All Store Views.
I was expecting that updating one of them updates the other. This is what is happening between default vs Finnish store views. Updating one of them affects the other. But between all store views and each store view updating one of them does not affect the other. I can also ask why even we have Use default value option available if sth has scope of website.

[image]

Just switching to

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer after playing around more with Magento2 and creating test and demo stores, store views and websites.
The key to understand the behaviour is that, **All Store Views** is sth like default values which can be used across all websites as default values, So take a look at the below image.
[image]

As you see All Store Views is sitting even on top of different websites. So All Store Views is in a way default values which can be uses across all store views.
Scope idea is still kept, an updating one store views in one specific website updates the rest.
Use default value, uses the value you have entered in the All store views, I would suggest renaming All store views to default values across websites or default values. All store views made me think it is the store views between one website.
Hope you find it helpful in future :)